# Событие MouseWheel, Windows Form C#

Tags: c#

Пишу приложение в VisualStudio Express 2010 (C#). Есть Panel, в которой расположен PictureBox. На панель повешено событие MouseWheel, при срабатывании которого выполняется масштабирование изображения PictureBox. Выглядит так:

```
//Объявление события
this.Panel.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.Panel_MouseWheel);

//Обработчик
private void Panel_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
//масштабирование
}
```

Так вот, на моём ноутбуке работает всё прекрасно. Попробовал на ноутбуке товарища - скролл мыши не перехватывает, скролл точпадом - перехватывает.
Скролл на мыши у товарища рабочий. Подскажите в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Запустите Spy++ и посмотрите, какие сообщения приходят в окно при движении колеса.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, PictureBox не получает WM_MOUSEWHEEL.

Проверить можно так:

```
var f = new Form() { Height = 500, Width = 800 };
var p = new PictureBox() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 100 };
var v = new MessageView(p) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = f };
Application.AddMessageFilter(v);
f.ShowDialog();

// ...

class MessageView : RichTextBox, IMessageFilter {
    private Control c;
    public MessageView(Control c) { this.c = c; }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        if(m.HWnd == c.Handle)
            this.AppendText(m + "\n");   // m.Msg = 0x20a (WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        return false;
    }
}
```